# Can I do a background api call when the app is terminated/killed by the user in react native?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-background-fetch

Can I do a background api call when the app is terminated/killed by the user in react native?

I tried with react-native-background-actions & react-native-background-timer.

Working fine in android but not in IOS when user terminate/kill the app

Answer (score 0):

iOS have stricter policies about allowing background tasks to run when the app is killed, probably thats why you are facing this issue. Its not impossible to achieve what you are trying to, however its not very reliable, given that apple have full control of these tasks and when/if they are executed. You can try https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch, its very well documented and might do the job for you.